# How I can turn into 4d array to 2d array in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
row=int(input("Number of rows for two dimensional list please:")) 
print("Enter",row,"rows as a list of int please:")

numbers = []
for i in range(row):
    numbers.append(input().split())
array=[0]*row
for i in range(row):
    array[i]=[numbers]



print(array)
```

## The program inputs are

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

## This program output:

```
[[[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]], [[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]], [[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]]]
```

## How can I turn into this 2 dimensional array like this

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a list comprehension, and iterate trough the lines, using `splitlines`, then split the lines, then convert the values to an integer:

```
row=input("Number of rows for two dimensional list please:")
print([list(map(int,i.split())) for i in row.splitlines()])
```